# Determinant equals 1 whereas Inverse unequal to the transpose?

Tags: matrices, orthogonal-matrices, transpose

So briefly: Given the matrix $A$ with det$(A) = 1$:

$\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & a & b\\ 0 & 1 & c\\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{array}\right)$

Its inverse however is set by

$\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & -a & a\,c-b\\ 0 & 1 & -c\\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{array}\right)$

If I'm not mistaken, that's not $A^T$. Also I hold the opinion that this kind of matrices with the property of  $\det= \pm 1$ belong to the orthogonal group, which is why I came for the conclusion.

Comment: It doesn't belong to the orthogonal group (since $A^{-1}\ne A^T$ as you noted). Maybe you mixed it up with the *special linear group*?

Comment: Ah, I assumed every matrix with det $\pm$ 1 is a member of the orthogonal group.

Comment: No, the other way: Every matrix in the orthogonal group has $\det \pm 1$ but your example shows that the converse is not true.

Comment: Is there something special about det $= 1$ though? Do these matrices automatically count to Lie groups?

Comment: @Leon The orthogonal group preserves all _distances_, whereas the special linear group preserves _volumes_ (which is what $\det A$ represents). The matrix you have represents a shear; the effects might be slightly easier to see in the two-dimensional analogue, where you can see that volumes of rectangles are preserved but vector lengths are not.

Comment: The matrices with determinant 1 are 'interesting' in part because they also form a group, since the determinant of a product is the product of the determinants.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Ah, thank you for pointing out the symmetry property (constant volume),  which should make it a Lie group

Comment: Leon, matrix groups (over real numbers, say) are linear groups and hence automatically Lie groups. No symmetry property needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about $A^{-1}$. Since it is distinct from $A^T$, the conclusion is that $A$ is *not* an orthogonal matrix. Although the determinant of every orthogonal matrix is indeed $\pm1$, most matrices whose determinant is $\pm1$ are not orthogonal.